# How to update the dependency version in the parent pom when building in Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, dependencies, pom.xml

I have a project with the following pom :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>...</groupId>
         <artifactId>...</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1-RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.bb.cc.dd</groupId>
    <artifactId>Proj1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>bla bla bla</name>
    <description>abcfgd</description>


    <!-- Configuration of repositories for dependency resolution -->

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>  
            <dependency>
                <groupId>aa.bb.cc.dd</groupId>
                <artifactId>dependencyProj</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0</version>
                <type>war</type>        
            </dependency>   
            </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement> 
</project>
```

What I am trying to achieve :
When I start a build in Jenkins for Proj1,I should have an option to start a build for dependencyProj and if that succeeds insert the new version(2.0.1) in the pom of the Proj1 and complete the build for Proj 1.So the updated pom (release version) should look like this  (before the maven plugin updates it for the development iteration) :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>...</groupId>
         <artifactId>...</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1-RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.bb.cc.dd</groupId>
    <artifactId>Proj1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>bla bla bla</name>
    <description>abcfgd</description>


    <!-- Configuration of repositories for dependency resolution -->

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>  
            <dependency>
                <groupId>aa.bb.cc.dd</groupId>
                <artifactId>dependencyProj</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.1</version>
                <type>war</type>        
            </dependency>   
            </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement> 
</project>
```

Note : I tried the "Trigger build" option from the main project and the Post Build Step "Build other projects" from dependency project but none of them update the versions when cheking in to git.Just to add i used the maven release plugin here.
Is it possible to configure jenkins to update the version of the dependent projects in the pom?

Comment: I think you are trying to get dependencyProj available in you parent project build. you can include this as module for parent pom and it will include that proj.

Comment: That is not an option for me since the dependencyProj is common project used by various other projects. I also have multiple dependency project so i cannot include them all as module.

Comment: In that case just right `LATEST` in the version and maven should pick the latest version available for that project.

Comment: This might not completely solve my use case. In the first place i am trying to find a way to have an option to start the build on the dependency project when i build the main project and if not required i might not build the dependency (if there are no changes).If i manage to find that then in those cases LATEST might pick up a version that is not intended or tested(if updated by some other team).